# Ansible playbook to create VM in vSphere

Tags: scripting, ansible, virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere

I need a **Ansible** playbook to create an VM in my **vSphere**, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Now do you have a real question related to programming on a specific problem you are facing when trying to implement this ? Please have a look at the help section of the site, more specifically [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

you have create a new VM (without OS), is normal you receive the error: **NO OS FOUND**

Try this:

```
---
- name : To test VM creation on vSphere
  hosts  : localhost
  gather_facts : False
  tasks  :
   - name : Including Secrets
     include_vars:
             file: ../secrets.yml
             name: secret

   - name : Create a new vm from template
     vmware_guest :
        hostname: "{{secret.hostname}}"        
        user: "{{secret.username}}"
        password: "{{secret.password}}"
        validate_certs: no
        datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
        folder: /vm
        name: an-new-vm
        state: poweredon
        guest_id: centos64Guest
        esxi_hostname: "{{ hostname }}"
        cdrom:
        - iso_path: "{{ [datastore1]path/to/file.iso }}"
          type: iso 
        customization:
             autologon: True
             existing_vm: True
        hardware: 
            num_cpus: 2
            memory_mb: 8192
        disk:
           - size_gb: 40
             datastore: datastore-2
        networks:
        - name: VM Network
          type: dhcp
          device_type: vmxnet3
          hostname: ansible-testing.domain.da
          allow_guest_control: True
          wait_for_ip_address: yes
     register : new_vm

   - debug:
       var: new_vm
```

For more info see this link:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/vmware/vmware_guest_module.html